# PHP login doesnt check for password

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I found this [forum thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75181/simple-php-login-register-script-with-oop) to make a log-in and registration system, but it doesn't check if password is correct, only username.

This is my log-in page code:

```
<?php
 include('config.php');
 session_start();

 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
  // username and password sent from Form
  $emailusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['emailusername']); 
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->conn,$_POST['password']); 
  $password = md5($password);

  $sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username='$emailusername' or email = '$emailusername' and password='$password'";
  $result=mysqli_query($obj->conn,$sql);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $active=$row['active'];
  $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);


  // If result matched $username and $username, table row must be 1 row
   if($count==1)
   {
     $_SESSION['login_user'] = $emailusername;
     header("location: index.php");
   }
   else 
   {
     $error="<div style ='color:#c53131'>Your Login Name or Password is invalid</div>";
   }
 }
?>
</div>

<form class="fl" action="login.php" method="post">
    <label>Username:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="emailusername"/><br />
    <br/>
    <label>Password:</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>
```

This is the table I use:

```
    "uid INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,".
    "username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE,".
    "password VARCHAR(50),".
    "name VARCHAR(100),".
    "email VARCHAR(70) UNIQUE); ";
```

I am new to PHP and have no clue how to make it check if password is correct or incorrect. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Stop. Even if you get this to work: this is primitive code, so it is questionable if you should invest into this. A few issues here, but one thing really pops out: `passwords should never be stored inside a database`. There is no reason for that and you only create a huge security issue by this.

Comment: Have you heard of operator precedence?

Comment: may you look at this [link](http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2006-12-15-never-store-passwords-in-a-database.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try your query as below :

```
SELECT uid FROM users 
WHERE (username='$emailusername' or email = '$emailusername') 
and password='$password'";
```

Answer (score 1):

CHECK YOUR Query

```
$sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE (username='$emailusername' OR email = '$emailusername') AND(password='$password')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the bellow query :

```
SELECT uid 
FROM users 
WHERE (username='$emailusername' OR email = '$emailusername') 
AND password='$password'
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The query should be like this.

```
   $sql="SELECT uid FROM users WHERE (username='".$emailusername."' or email = '".$emailusername."') and password='".$password."'";
```

If you have to use different logical operators, you should add brackets individual evaluation. Moreover, you have to pass `username` and `password` as strings.